# Can I add a fan to my Dell Inspiron 15 355?

Tags: fan

I’m using [Dell Inspiron 15 3552](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3552-laptop/docs) laptop with optical drive and non touch display and my laptop has no fan.

I need to add a fan to my laptop. I can’t use my laptop for long time because it’s getting hot soon.

Can I install a fan myself?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the fact, you might just want to get one of those fans that you can get for all computers where you place it under them. But you want to get more efficiency out so you want to add heat pipes.
That would not be worth it, so just get the fan mention by @harrymc.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell Inspiron 15 3552 laptop does have a fan, but yours is probably faulty.

This is not a new computer, so finding replacement parts would be difficult.
One example candidate that I found is on
[Ali Express](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33018290593.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.2ae93931EFCZXC&algo_pvid=e7053274-54d5-4625-9b24-133b808b7e28&algo_expid=e7053274-54d5-4625-9b24-133b808b7e28-9&btsid=0b0a22a415944986509474989ec5e4&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_),
where apparently you get 5 of them for US $26.30.

However, getting to the fan requires basically almost totally disassembling the laptop.
I suggest to avoid doing it yourself unless you have very good technical knowledge.

See the following video for the process of disassembling (assembling is not included):
[Dell Inspiron 3552 - Disassembly and fan cleaning - Laptop repair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYfjrLQznYs).

Comment: fwiw, aliexpress parts might be NOS, third shift runs or refurbs. caveat emptor.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: That was an example only.

Comment: Why downvote the only answer which shows how to reach the fan and why it's hard to do?

Comment: \o/ Why assume its me? I was pointing out something about aliexpress parts, since a *lot* of stuff there is pulls

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I didn't assume it was you - only one comment was addressed to you.

Comment: @harrymc I bought this laptop in a dell showroom and they gave me 1 year warranty too. I haven't noticed it naver had a fan.

Comment: There is a plastic panel to replace a fan.see here[link](https://jestineyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/3-6.jpg) .I think i can install a fan my self without heat pipe or anything else.

Comment: Your model seems different than the [one in the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeptQ.jpg). Strange, as they are both labelled "Dell Inspiron 3552", or maybe just a different view-point. You might get by without total disassembly. Note very well while doing so where goes each disassembled part, for re-assembly is often the harder task.

Comment: I have experience in assemble & disassemble. what does mean by heat sink plate(processor heat sink plate) that my laptop have instead of fan?

Comment: The heat sink transfers heat to where it can be dissipated. Possibly there is a fan connected on the other side. If there isn't one, then your model is strange.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the fan on ebay for under 10, free ship.  You really should not run it without cooling; there is a high risk of damaging components.  Instructions for replacing the fan are at several places online.

Comment: This us wring. Systems will doen-throttle to protect themselves.